# Android Studio: Crear una imagen a partir de recortar otra guardada

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Buenas. Tengo guardada un foto tomada por la cámara. A continuación quiero que una serie de fotos sean cargadas en un RecyclerView. Este RecyclerView es una lista de CardViews. Todo esto está implementado y funcionando.

El problema viene en que cuando se carga cada foto en el CardView, las cuales he redimensionado para que quepan en un ImageView, salen distorsionadas, lo que es lógico porque las dimensiones no cuadran.

Entonces, lo que quiero es crear un nuevo Bitmap recortando la imagen tomada por la cámara y guardada en la memoria. Puedo recuperar el path ya que lo tengo guardado en una bd. Las fotos tomadas son siempre del mismo tamaño, por lo que no es necesario abrir un Intent para elegir el recorte, sino que quiero capturar la mitad superior de la imagen.

Este método es el que me redimensiona la foto capturada por la cámara.

```
public Bitmap redimensionarImagen(Bitmap img){

    //se toma como referencia para las nuevas medidas el tamaño en píxeles de la pantalla del terminal

    int newWidth = (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*4)/5;
    int newHeight = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels/4;

    Bitmap resizedBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, newWidth, newHeight, false);


        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Bueno, pues lo que quiero es capturar un recorte de del Bitmap img que sea la mitad superior de la imagen, y luego aplicarle el createScaledBitmap a esa nuevo recorte.

Comment: Codigo por favor

Comment: Podrias pasar el código por favor? :D

Comment: Ya tienes el código. Gracias